# Rails: find_by_sql and virtual column

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to display a list with tags plus the number of elements (in my example "Tasks") for each tag.

For this purpose I created the following method in my Tag model:

```
def self.find_with_count
  find_by_sql 'SELECT
                 Tag.name,
                 COUNT(Tag.name) AS taskcount
               FROM
                 tags AS Tag
                 INNER JOIN tags_tasks tt ON tt.tag_id = Tag.id
                 INNER JOIN tasks t ON tt.task_id = t.id
               WHERE
                 t.finished = 0
                 AND t.deleted = 0
               GROUP BY
                 Tag.name
               ORDER BY
                 Tag.name'
end
```

The method returns the correct tag names, but for some reason the taskcounts are not in the result. The result looks like

```
[#<Tag name: "hello">, #<Tag name: "world">]
```

As this approach doesn't seem to work, I'm wondering what the Rails-way is to accomplish such a task. Thanks!

Comment: Excellent question! I know this is an old post, but it saved me on a big project I am working on... so, thanks!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The count is there, you just can't see it since taskcount is not an attribute Rails creates for that class Task, because it isn't a column that it can see. You have to use the attributes call to find it.
Sample:

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  def taskcount
    attributes['taskcount']
  end
end

Tag.find_with_count.each do |t|
  puts "#{t.name}: #{t.taskcount}"
end
```

Answer (score 10):

The "Rails way" is to use a `counter_cache`:

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tag_tasks
  has_many :tasks, :through => :tag_tasks
end

# the join model
class TagTask < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tag, :counter_cache => true
  belongs_to :task
end

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tag_tasks
  has_many :tags, :through => :tag_tasks
end
```

This requires adding a `tag_tasks_count` column on your 'Tag' table.

If you add a `named_scope` to Tag like so:

```
class Tag ...
  named_scope :active, lambda { { :conditions => { 'deleted' => 0, 'finished' => 0 } } }
end
```

Then you can replace all `Tag.find_by_count` with `Tag.active`.  Use it like this:

```
Tag.active.each do |t|
  puts "#{t.name} (#{t.tag_tasks_count})"
end
```

Comment: Hadn't spotted the counter cache, or indeed named scopes. Very nice  -thanks for explaining.

Comment: Thanks for the idea with the counter cache, that seems to be a cleaner solution than using find_by_sql.