# Rails: setting column alias attribute with find_by_sql

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

When I use a column alias in a query with find_by_sql, it doesn't appear to be set in the result objects, even when I add an attr_accessor for the property.

```
class Country < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessor :average_score

  def self.sorted_by_average_score
    sql = "SELECT country_id, AVG(score) AS average_score, countries.name " +
    "FROM players " +
    "INNER JOIN countries ON players.country_id = countries.id " +
    "GROUP BY country_id "
    Country.find_by_sql(sql)
  end
end
```

I would expect to be able to do this:

```
countries = Country.sorted_by_average_score.first.average_score
```

...but it always returns nil, even though a value is definitely returned from the query.

Can anyone explain to me why the attribute isn't set in the object?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You don't need to use `attr_accessor`, see neutrino's explanation.  You just need to access your virtual column by using the `attributes` hash.  This question is the same as [Rails: find_by_sql and virtual column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582431/rails-find-by-sql-and-virtual-column).   Sample code for your example:

```
countries = Country.sorted_by_average_score.first.attributes['average_score']
```

Answer (score 6):

Because `attr_accessors` have nothing to do with the way ActiveRecord treats your columns. I've shown it in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448414/why-does-attr-accessor-clobber-the-existing-variables-in-this-model-in-ruby-on-ra/1448438#1448438). Basically all the stuff going on in finders that touches columns, works with the `attributes` hash, not with the instance variables that your accessors declare.

edit: actually my answer doesn't answer the question completely. it just explains why `attr_accessor` could not be of any help here. looking forward to see someone do the rest of the job :)

Comment: Although it's correct that your answer doesn't answer the actual question, but it's good to know what's happening under the hood. Thanks.