# group by + sum on multiple columns in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, sum

I need to get a list of locations ordered by the number of picture that I have in the DB for these locations, here is my query

```
Location.select(:city).group(:city).order("SUM(images_count) DESC").sum(:images_count)
```

This worked like a charm, unfortunately, I now need to add province and country to prevent ambiguities to arise, so I now have this

```
Location.select(:city, :province, :country).group(:city, :province, :country).order("SUM(images_count) DESC").sum(:images_count)
```

And this is not working :(

Could someone help me out with this query?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I'm not very proud of my solution but it works:

```
Location.group(:city, :province, :country)
        .select(:city, :province, :country, "SUM(images_girl_count) as sum_images_count")
        .order("sum_images_count DESC")
        .collect{ |location| [location.city, location.province, location.country, location.sum_images_count] }
```

Any feedback?

Comment: Thanks for this! I had a similar problem with grouping and summing in one query. Did you test this also on Postgres?

Comment: grouping is hell on postgres! but it's the standard... Yes, my app is on postgres, so I confirm that this is working

Answer (score 2):

The sum method only use one column while grouping, try this :

```
Location.select(:city, :province, :country, "SUM(images_count) as sum_images_count").group(:city, :province, :country).order("sum_images_count DESC")
```

It may be a better way though.

I hope it would help.

Comment: It works... But, I don't have the sum in the result, which I would love to have, I only get City, Province, Country, sum_images_count is missing, do you know how I could get it too?

Comment: Its strange..you should have the sum_images_count in the attributes, have you tried this in the console ?

Comment: yes, I tried this on the console with both SQLlite and Postgres

Comment: See this post on virtual attributes http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582431/rails-find-by-sql-and-virtual-column