# Mysql2::Result to Objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mysql2

How I can convert Mysql2::Result result to some object?
I use:

```
@users = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT sum(summ) as prize, u.* FROM `tournaments` t, `users` u WHERE u.id = t.user_id GROUP BY t.user_id ORDER BY prize desc LIMIT 10")
```

I need to map this result to some object, or smthg like this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My understanding is that you can execute a sql query like that on any model and it will return the data as instances of that model. Read up on [find_by_sql](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#method-c-find_by_sql). This is the example from the docs. Notice that is returns a Post object:

```
Post.find_by_sql "SELECT p.title, c.author FROM posts p, comments c WHERE p.id = c.post_id"
> [#<Post:0x36bff9c @attributes={"title"=>"Ruby Meetup", "first_name"=>"Quentin"}>, ...]
```

Rails 3 query syntax should give you all you need to get this info though. I would stay away from raw SQL as much as possible, you can find yourself tied to a specific database very quickly like that. Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4855821/group-by-sum-on-multiple-columns-in-rails-3) for some inspiration.

Passing params to find_by_sql can be done like this:

```
irb(main):015:0> y Location.find_by_sql(["select address, name from locations where name = :name and address = :address", {:address => "Arts Court 2 Daly Ave, Ottawa, ON", :name => "Studio B"}])
--- 
- !ruby/object:Location 
  attributes: 
  name: Studio B
  address: Arts Court 2 Daly Ave, Ottawa, ON
  attributes_cache: {}

changed_attributes: {}

destroyed: false
marked_for_destruction: false
new_record: false
previously_changed: {}
```

Comment: Thanks, how I can pass two or more params to the find_by_sql method?

Comment: Solved with Question.find_by_sql([sql, '2011-04-06', 1])

Comment: I added an example to my answer.