# Group by a column and then get the sum of another column in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I'm a beginner using Rails 4.2.1 with Postgresql to create a personal stock portfolio like in Yahoo Finance. Going to "portfolio/:id" should show the show.html.erb file below for each portfolio. Each portfolio is associated with the holdings table which contains the data for which stock a portfolio has and how many shares of each stock a portfolio has. **If a user has two of the same stocks in the same portfolio, the app must get a sum of the "amount" column from both of those two rows and and make one row with the same data in addition to the sum of the amount.**

**Models**

```
User
has_many :portfolios
has_many :holdings

Portfolio
belongs_to :user
has_many :holdings

Holding
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :stock
belongs_to :portfolio

Stock
has_many :holdings
```

**Database schema**

```
table "holdings"
t.integer  "user_id"
t.integer  "stock_id"
t.integer  "portfolio_id"
t.integer  "amount"
end

table "portfolios"
t.integer  "user_id"
t.string   "name"
end

table "stocks"
t.string   "symbol"
end
```

**PortfoliosController**

```
def show
@holdings = @portfolio.holdings # can't figure out what to do next.
end

# As it is, this just shows rows for every new holding transaction.
```

**show.html.erb**

```
 <% @holdings.each do |holdings| %>
 <tr>
    <td><%= holdings.portfolio.user.name %></td>
    <td><%= holdings.portfolio.name %></td>
    <td><%= holdings.stock.symbol %></td>
    <td><%= holdings.amount %></td>
  </tr>
 <% end %>
```

**Errors**

```
@holdings = @portfolio.holdings.sum(:amount, :group => "stock_id" :order=> "sum(amount) DESC")
```

Causes this error:

```
NoMethodError at /portfolios/22
undefined method `each' for 171:Fixnum

# And by the way, 171 is the correct sum but it needs to work with the looped table
```

This:

```
@holdings = @portfolio.holdings.group(:portfolio_id).sum(:amount)
```

Causes this error:

```
NoMethodError at /portfolios/22
undefined method `portfolio' for [22, 171]:Array
```

**I just can't seem to get it to work with the each loop.**

Comment: where did you see this syntax `sum(:amount, :group => "stock_id" :order=> "sum(amount) DESC")`.. I never saw it..

Comment: @R_O_R Hey sorry I lost the page. I've been through hundreds of pages about this topic.

Comment: @portfolio.holdings.group(:stock_id).select("SUM(amount) as total, holdings.*").order("total DESC")` check this

Comment: just add columns which you want to display in select list

Comment: what columns you need?

Comment: I need to sum the amount column in the holdings table per unique stock. I think I need the stock_id column to group it though.

Comment: `@holdings = Portfolio.joins(:holdings).where('holdings.portfolio_id = ?', params[:id]).select("SUM(amount) as total, holdings.stock_id, holdings.user_id, holdings.portfolio_id").group('holdings.stock_id').order("total DESC")` try this

Comment: @test I did it!!! Thanks for your help, you kept me from giving up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After countless hours spent, I found the solution. This was incredibly difficult to find. I actually found the answer on this page: [group by + sum on multiple columns in rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4855821/group-by-sum-on-multiple-columns-in-rails-3)

So what I changed was:

In the controller:

```
@holdings = @portfolio.holdings.select(:stock_id, :portfolio_id, 
"SUM(amount) as sum_amount").group(:stock_id,
:portfolio_id).order("sum_amount DESC")
```

And in the view:

```
<tr>
  <td><%= holdings.portfolio.user.name %></td>
  <td><%= holdings.portfolio.name %></td>
  <td><%= holdings.stock.symbol %></td>
  <td><%= holdings.sum_amount %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```