# Rails: Sum column by group

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I created this code that pulls the information I need.

```
def index
  @votes = Vote.all
  @originalitysum = Vote.group(:widget_id).sum(:originality)
end
```

It returns a hash:

```
{188=>5, 160=>2}
```

I now need to match the key to the widget_id and return the value. I.E:

If the widget_id is 188 return 5.

```
<% @votes.group(:widget_id).each do |vote| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= vote.widget.name %></td>
    <td><%= vote.widget.store %></td>
    <td><%=  %></td> <!-- This needs to be the total Originality -->
    <td><%= vote.interest %></td>
    <td><%= vote.rating %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

I'm open to changing this if some other way makes more sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

Controller

```
def index
@votes = Vote.all
@originalitysum = Vote.select([:widget_id, :originality]).group('widget_id').sum(:originality)
@votecount =  Vote.group(:widget_id).count(:originality)
@votes = Vote.select(:widget_id, 
  "SUM(originality) as originality_sum", 
  "SUM(interest) as interest_sum", 
  "SUM(rating) as rating_sum").group(:widget_id).order("rating_sum DESC")
end
```

The view

```
<% @votes.group(:burger_id).each do |vote| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= vote.widget.name %></td>
    <td><%= vote.widget.store %></td>
    <td><%= vote.originality_sum %></td>
    <td><%= vote.interest_sum %></td>
    <td><%= vote.rating_sum %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Thanks to this answer in this link, I was able to parse it together.
[Group by a column and then get the sum of another column in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30701465/group-by-a-column-and-then-get-the-sum-of-another-column-in-rails?rq=1)

The added bonus is that it allowed me to easily sum the other columns as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the originality sum with `@originalitysum[vote.widget.id]`